# Show 3 images on 1st row and 3 images on second row on collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I dragged a collectionview on to my xib, set the constraints as leading,trailing,top and height.

The coding part is given as...

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
           let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5

    collectionview2.delegate = self
    collectionview2.dataSource = self
    collectionview2.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ident")

    }
  }


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 5
    }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
 switch indexPath.item {
      case 0,1:
        return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16) / 2, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16) / 2)
      default:
        return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32) / 3, height:  (UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / 3)
      }
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ident", for: indexPath)
      cell.backgroundColor = .red
      return cell

}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099567/how-to-show-a-collectionview-like-facebook-upload-image-using-swift-4) is the link I have referred. 
But it is not working and I'm seeing just 5 equal width and height cells one after the other.

What am I doing wrong...?

**EDIT 1:** 
I would also like to show one long cell on left and 2 small cells on right like so...

What changes do I make to my answer so that I can achieve this...?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks perfect but you may forgot to confirm the FlowLayout Protocol. 
so,
you just need to confirm the below protocol in your code,

> UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Hope this way may help you.

Comment: confirming to the delegate made it work @Ahemadabbas Vagh...one more concern..how do I show one long cell on left and 2 small cells on right ..? I have edited the question with a pic..

Comment: we can do it by changing the flow layout for more info refer below link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498172/custom-layout-for-collection-view-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

You've to try this

Confirm `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

e.g.

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screeSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let numOfCell:Int = 3 //Number of items you want
        let spaceOfCell:CGFloat = (CGFloat((numOfCell + 1)*10)) //Space between Cells

        return CGSize(width: Int(screeSize.width - spaceOfCell) / numOfCell, height: Int(screeSize.width - spaceOfCell) / numOfCell)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.00
        //Verticle space between line
    }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10.00 //Space Between Items You want
    }
```

Hope it helps :)