# Can we specify the number of rows that can be shown in each section of a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, tvos

Im currently working on a `TvOS` App, in this i have one collection view with multiple `sections` and it has multiple `rows` under it. Will it be possible to limit the number of rows per section as 1?

I have tried using `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` function delegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return 1
}
```

This is not working and if i try to move my focus the row in the section below also starts to Move, Please help me find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

`minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` has nothing to do with the number of sections or rows.

You have to maintain your data source array that each section array contains only one item.

Or if you actually have an one-dimensional data source array return 1 in `numberOfRows` and `datasourcearray.count` in `numberOfSections`. Then you have `datasourcearray.count` sections with one row respectively.

Comment: Hi Vadian, Thanks for the answer. 
But i need to show multiple items in a single row

It shoudl look like.

Section Title 1
ROW 1 ---->item1,2,3,4

Section Title 2
ROW 2----->item 1,2,3,4

But currently My View Looks like 


Section title 1
ROW 1--->Item 1,2
ROW 2---->Item 3, 4

Section Title 2
ROW 1--->Item 5,6
ROW 2---->Item 7,8

Please help

Comment: This is pretty contradictory to your statement *Will it be possible to limit the number of rows per section as 1?*

Comment: Yeah number of rows should be one :) But it showld have multiple items.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom layout for that. Please refer to [this Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) for an example like Pinterest in **Swift 4**

Similar question:
 [Custom layout for collection view in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498172/custom-layout-for-collection-view-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You need to,

1. `return` `1` in `UICollectionViewDataSource's` `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` method and
2. `return` `sectionsCount` in `numberOfSections(in:)`, where `sectionsCount` is the total number of sections.

This is what you should implement to get that working,

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return sectionsCount
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

The method that you've implemented has a different purpose and doesn't define the `items/sections` in the `collectionView`.

> **collectionView(_:,layout:,minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt:)**
>
> Asks the delegate for the spacing between successive rows or columns
>   of a section.

Comment: hi PG Dev,
  The above solution will give one item per row,but i need a collection view that has multiple sections, and one row in each section consisting of multiple items.

I have no problem with sections :) My problem is to show one row under each section that has multiple items.

Thanks :)

Comment: That kind of nesting doesn't exist in `collectionView` as of now.